# Call to a member function execute() on bool

Tags: php, sql

I am not sure why this stmt is wrong. Perhaps someone could tell me?
I follow this tutorial and the code is working there but not working for me. I checked all the varibals and everything seems about right.

```
  public function insertForPost($postID, $content){
    $table = $this->getTableName();
    var_dump($this->pdo);
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare(
      "INSERT INTO `$table`, (`content`, `post_id`) VALUES (:content, :postID)"
    );
    $stmt->execute([
      'content' => $content,
      'postID' => $postID
  ]);
  }
```

My var_dump output is:

```
object(PDO)#9 (0) { }
```

Comment: No comma needed after `$table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the comma

```
INSERT INTO `$table`, (`content` ...
                    ^-----here
```

If you check the error output in the logs then you will see the exact SQL error message. These error messages are extremely accurate and point to the exact part of the query that throws the error.